# Hacer un Trigger actualizando un campo con UPDATE y con DELETE

Tags: sql, trigger, update

Tengo una tabla llamada Ciudad:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ciudad(
    Id          varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    DptId       varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    Nombre      varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    Version     Timestamp NULL,
    CreatedAt   datetimeoffset NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
    UpdatedAt   datetimeoffset NULL,
    Deleted     bit NOT NUll DEFAULT(0),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Ciudad] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ciudad_DptId] FOREIGN KEY (DptId) REFERENCES dbo.Dpto(Id) 
)
```

El campo `UpdatedAt` se tiene que actualizar cada que se hace un UPDATE en el registro. ¿como lo puedo hacer con un Trigger?

De momento solo tengo esto:

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Update ON dbo.Ciudad AFTER UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @id as VARCHAR
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(@id ,16,-1)
    UPDATE Ciudad SET UpdatedAt = getdate() WHERE Id = @id; 
END
```

**DELETE**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Eliminar ON dbo.Ciudad INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
DECLARE @id as VARCHAR
BEGIN
    UPDATE Ciudad SET UpdatedAt = getdate(), Deleted = 1 WHERE Id = @id; 
    RAISERROR('CAMPO DELETED ACTUALIZADO A TRUE',16,-1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

La idea es que el delete no borre el registro si no que actualice el campo `Deleted` pero no me funcionan los Triggers

Comment: Es correcto el doble apostrofe en RAISERROR?

Comment: tiene razon lo que pasa es que Azure no me acepta la creaciuon del trigger y me toca enviarlo en un `execute dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N' -- creacion del trigger aqui -- `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, asi lo deje:

**UPDATE**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='tr_Ciudad_Update' AND type='TR')
   DROP TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Update

execute dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Update ON dbo.Ciudad AFTER UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @id as VARCHAR(36)
SELECT @id = id FROM deleted
BEGIN
    UPDATE Ciudad SET UpdatedAt = getdate() WHERE Id = @id 
END
'
```

**DELETE**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='tr_Ciudad_Eliminar' AND type='TR')
   DROP TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Eliminar

execute dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Ciudad_Eliminar ON dbo.Ciudad INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
DECLARE @id as VARCHAR(36)
SELECT @id = id FROM deleted
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Deleted FROM Ciudad WHERE id = @id) = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            UPDATE Ciudad SET Deleted = 1 WHERE Id = @id;
        END
    ELSE
        print ''El campo ya esta eliminado''
END
'
```